# Complex sorting order by starting and ending dates on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, sql-order-by

I have an events table with `starting_date` and `ending_date`. I want the to sort them like the following:

There are **3 groups of rows** and they should appear sequentially, each group with it's order. The **groups** are as follow:

- Group 1: `starting_date = curdate() and ending_date = curdate()`. It's rows should be ordered by `id asc`.
- Group 2: `starting_date <= curdate() and ending_date > curdate()`. It's elements should be ordered by `ending_date  asc`
- Group 3: `starting_date > curdate()`. It's elements should be ordered by `starting date asc`

Supposing today is `may 21`, this is a sample of the output i need:

```
| id | starting_date | ending_date |

// Group 1
| 1  |    may 21     |    may 21   |
| 2  |    may 21     |    may 21   |

// Group 2
| *  |    may 20     |    may 23   |
| *  |    may 15     |    may 25   |
| *  |    may 17     |    may 26   |
| *  |    may 21     |    may 27   |

// Group 3
| *  |    may 23     |    may 25   |
| *  |    may 24     |    may 25   |
```

As you can see, each group appears in sequence, and each row inside a group is ordered by the specified `order by`.

So far I've tried using `ORDER BY CASE WHEN` sentences but I find myself unable to understand if I should:

- Use multiple `CASE ... END` statements under the `ORDER BY`
- Use multiple `WHEN ... THEN` statements inside an `ORDER BY CASE ... END`
- Both, multiple `CASE` with multiple `when` inside each.
- This can't be done using `ORDER BY`.

This is one of the many `SELECT` sentences I've tried:

```
select events.id, events.starting_date, events.ending_date from events
    where events.ending_date >= CURDATE()
    order by
        case 
            when (events.starting_date = curdate() and events.ending_date = (curdate() + interval 23 hour + interval 59 minute)) then 
            0
            when (events.starting_date <= curdate() and events.ending_date > curdate()) then
            1
            when (events.starting_date > curdate()) then
            2
        end asc
```

This query put rows on the correct group, but they aren't ordered inside their respective group.

This other one puts the first group at the end.

```
order by

    case when (events.starting_date = curdate() and events.ending_date = (curdate() + interval 23 hour + interval 59 minute)) then events.id end asc,
    case when (events.starting_date <= curdate() and events.ending_date > curdate()) then events.ending_date end asc,
    case when (events.starting_date > curdate()) then events.starting_date end asc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sorting logic you are attempting to codify requires *two* sorting variables.  The first sort is based on to what group (1-3) each record belongs.  The second sort happens within each group.  The correct approach is to use the logic from the two attempts you made in your question.  The general form of the `ORDER BY` is:

```
ORDER BY group_number, something_else
```

where the group number is 1, 2, or 3, and the something else is the specific order for that group.  But the catch here is that `group_number` and `something_else` each have a separate `CASE` statement.  In the case of group 1, you would want `ORDER BY 1, events.id`.  I also added an `ELSE` condition to the `CASE` expressions to handle default cases not covered, and any such records will appear in a group at the bottom of the result set, sorted by `id`.

```
SELECT events.id, events.starting_date, events.ending_date
FROM events
WHERE events.ending_date >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY
    (CASE
        WHEN (events.starting_date = CURDATE() AND
              events.ending_date = (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 23 HOUR + INTERVAL 59 MINUTE))
            THEN 1
        WHEN (events.starting_date <= CURDATE() AND
              events.ending_date > CURDATE())
            THEN 2
        WHEN (events.starting_date > CURDATE())
            THEN 3
        ELSE 4
    END),
    (CASE
        WHEN (events.starting_date = CURDATE() AND
              events.ending_date = (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 23 HOUR + INTERVAL 59 MINUTE))
            THEN events.id
        WHEN (events.starting_date <= CURDATE() AND
              events.ending_date > CURDATE())
            THEN events.ending_date
        WHEN (events.starting_date > CURDATE())
            THEN events.starting_date
        ELSE events.id
    END)
```